# Oracle Analytics Get Summary Counts

Tags: oracle, count, analytics

Given this query, how can I get summary counts for each `Tree_ID`?

```
with tree_row
as (
select '1111' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '1111' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '2222' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '2222' as tree_id, 'CHIP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '3333' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '3333' as tree_id, 'CHIP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '3333' as tree_id, 'CHIP' as tree_product from dual
)
select distinct tree_id, 
       count(*) over (partition by tree_id, tree_product) as pulp_count,
       count(*) over (partition by tree_id, tree_product) as chip_count,
       count(*) over (partition by tree_id)               as tree_total
       from tree_row;
```

**Desired Result**

```
TREE_ID PULP_COUNT  CHIP_COUNT TREE_TOTAL
    1111     2           0            2
    2222     1           1            2
    3333     1           2            3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need analytic functions, you can use conditional aggregation - normal aggregation but with a case expression (the conditional part) to determine which rows to include in the count:

```
with tree_row
as (
select '1111' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '1111' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '2222' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '2222' as tree_id, 'CHIP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '3333' as tree_id, 'PULP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '3333' as tree_id, 'CHIP' as tree_product from dual union all
select '3333' as tree_id, 'CHIP' as tree_product from dual
)
select tree_id, 
       count(case when tree_product = 'PULP' then tree_id end) as pulp_count,
       count(case when tree_product = 'CHIP' then tree_id end) as chip_count,
       count(*)                                                as tree_total
       from tree_row
       group by tree_id;
```

| TREE_ID | PULP_COUNT | CHIP_COUNT | TREE_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2222 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3333 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sUuF7c1D)